# Merge two dataframes on DateTimeIndex ignoring the year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes, one is a series of measurements,

```
A = ID                 Value
2020-01-01 00:00:00    0.2
2020-01-01 01:00:00    0.2
                      ...
2020-12-31 22:00:00    0.6
2020-12-31 23:00:00    0.5
2021-01-01 00:00:00    0.4
2021-01-01 01:00:00    0.3
                      ...
2021-12-31 22:00:00    0.3
2021-12-31 23:00:00    0.2
```

The other one is a scaling value, which is the same for every year, but available with a DateTimeIndex of a specific year.

```
B = ID                 Value
2020-01-01 00:00:00    2
2020-01-01 01:00:00    3
                      ...
2020-12-31 22:00:00    10
2020-12-31 23:00:00    11
```

Is there a way to merge the two dataset, negelecting the year of the second dataset to get a dataframe like this:

```
A = ID                 ValueA  ValueB
2020-01-01 00:00:00    0.2     2
2020-01-01 01:00:00    0.2     3
                      ...
2020-12-31 22:00:00    0.6     10
2020-12-31 23:00:00    0.5     11
2021-01-01 00:00:00    0.4     2
2021-01-01 01:00:00    0.3     3
                      ...
2021-12-31 22:00:00    0.3     10
2021-12-31 23:00:00    0.2     11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and helper column defined by [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
df = (df1.assign(time=df.index.strftime('%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
         .merge(df2.assign(time=df2.index.strftime('%m-%d %H:%M:%S')), 
                    on='time', how='left', suffixes=('A','B'))
         .drop('time', axis=1))
```

Comment: Works. For my case I have to add month and day to the join, because the scaling value is not the same for each day. 

df.assign(time=df.index.time, month=df.index.month, day=df.index.day)
... 
 on=['time', 'month','day']

Comment: @dnrhead - You are right, then answer is edited by `strftime` with defined `MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format